# Javascript function in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following code sample trying to show an error message and redirect on click for all button and a tags...this works fine in Chrome and Firefox; any way I can get this to work in IE with a simple tweak?

```
 document.querySelector('body')
.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if
        (event.target.tagName === 'A' || event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') { 
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Test");     window.open('www.yahoo.com', '_self');
    }
});
```

Comment: what version of IE?

Comment: Error message in the console? Is it running in compat mode of a really old IE?

Comment: I thought it might be an old version of IE...but after checking its running IE11.

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd elaborate on what's wrong instead of just declaring that it doesn't work. What happens? What *doesn't* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: ... None of this looks like jQuery.

Comment: "Not Working" as in the links get clicked, and the code doesnt trigger. The regular hyperlinks work. The code to prevent default, show a popup, and redirect does not trigger.

Answer (score 1):

[`.addEventListener`](https://www.google.fr/search?q=addEventListener&oq=addEventListener&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.661j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is the proper DOM method for attaching the event.

For all other browsers you can use `.addEventListener` and for I.E you can use [`.attachEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/attachEvent)

Comment: This didnt seem to work either. I'm told it could be an issue with event.target.tagName...is there an alternative to this?